# List<T> and GetRange() issue in derived Class

Tags: c#, list

I have a class that implements a list of MyItems.
I want a method cutting of some elements from that list and it should return the removed items.
This is what I tried:

```
public class MyItemList : List<MyItem>
{
    ...

    public MyItemList cutOff(int count)
    {
        MyItemList result = this.GetRange(0, count);
        this.RemoveRange(0, count);
        return result;
    }
```

Unfortunately the GetRange() returns List but not MyItemList :(
How can I handle this in a better way?
Casting doesn't work.
There must be an elegant way to solve this very simple problem and stay inside the type MyItemList (without dirty hacks).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered using composition instead of inheritance?

Comment: Ilya is right; it would probably be better for you to implement `IList<MyItem>` and then use a private `List<MyItem>` internally as your storage. That way you are free to decide to go with another implementation strategy should you change your mind in the future. Ask yourself whether a `MyItemList` *is a special kind of `List<MyItem>`*, or if it is *something that acts like a list of MyItems*. The former is class inheritance, the latter is interface implementation.

Comment: I agree with you two. Also, if you're looking to just have some extra List functions such as `CutOff` then you could used extension methods and stick to generic types, i.e. `List<MyItem>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick, but  I strongly suggest to redesign towards composition, where you will store List internally

```
public class MyItemList : List<MyItem>
{
    public MyItemList(){}

    public MyItemList(IEnumerable<MyItem> sequence): base(sequence) {}

    public MyItemList cutOff(int count)
    {
        MyItemList result = new MyItemList(this.GetRange(0, count));
        this.RemoveRange(0, count);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Also consider creating open generic type of your list like `MyList<T> : List<T>` or `MyList<T> : List<T> where T : MyItem` so that client of that class can take advantage of generics

**Edit:** ok, I've implemented generic version for `List<T>` as extension method, this will help you to more logic general to Lists outside your MyItemList class

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static List<T> CutOff<T>(this List<T> list, int count)
    {
        var result = list.GetRange(0, count);
        list.RemoveRange(0, count);
        return result;
    }
}
```

now you can

```
var list = new List<int> {1,2,3,4,5,6};

Console.WriteLine ("cutted items:");
Console.WriteLine (string.Join(Environment.NewLine, list.CutOff(2)));

Console.WriteLine ("items in list:");
Console.WriteLine (string.Join(Environment.NewLine, list));
```

prints:

```
cutted items:
1
2
items in list:
3
4
5
6
```

**Another note:**

I suggest to do this

```
public class MyItemList<T> : IList<T> where T : MyItem
{
     private List<T> list;

     //here will be implementation of all methods required by IList
     //that will simply delegate to list field

}
```

note that if all logic in `MyItemList` is general-purpose (that can be applied to `List<T>`, like `Cutoff` method), you probably don't need separate class. Also `where T : MyItem` is optional, only need if you access methods defined in `MyItem` at MyItemList

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer! If I understand you right you suggest to do something like this:
    public class MyItemList
    {
        List<MyItem> _list ;
        
        ...
        
        public MyItemList cutOff(int count)
        {
            MyItemList result = new MyItemList( _list.GetRange(0, count));
            _list.RemoveRange(0, count);
            return result;
        }

What is the advantage oft that solution? Why is it better?
I took inheritance to get more specific version of ListT with all methods available on ListT...

Answer (score 2):

You could just return a `List<MyItem>` or `MyItem[]` with the removed items.
or Use the List<> constructor that takes an ienumerable.

Haven't compiled this - but should be ok

```
public class MyItemList : List<MyItem>
{
   // def ctor
   public MyItemList() {}

   public MyItemList(IEnumerable<MyItems> items): base(items) {}

   public MyItemList cutOff(int count)
    {
        MyItemList result = new MyItemList(this.GetRange(0, count));
        this.RemoveRange(0, count);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well almost identical to llya's! there's the quick and the dead.

Answer (score 1):

Don't inherit from `List<MyItem>` (unless all you're trying to do is avoid typing angle brackets. Rather, *encapsulate* a `List<MyItem>` as your class' backing store and expose only the specific/methods and properties required by your problem domain. By inheriting from `List<MyObject>`, your are leaking implementation details and tying yourself to a particular type of backing store. You want to maintain the minimal public surface area required to get the job done. Doing so facilitates testing, and makes future change much easier.

If you want *interoperability* with standard SCG collection types, implement only the interfaces you need — preferably explicitly.